# Only allow 1 user login in Spring Sercurity

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I have two users: A and B, if user A login first, user B cant login util user A logout. Each user require three login info: storeId, storePassword, userPassword.

If user B same storeId with user A, do not allow login

If user B different storeId with user A, allow login

I use ServletContext to hold users logged, and when logged user click logout, I will remove that user from ServletContext. But I cant hanle when user close brower intead of click logout. I think this is not a good idea

Here is my code

```
@Override
public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    //redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, "/login");
    // do whatever you want
    ServletContext context = request.getSession().getServletContext();
    Object _auths = context.getAttribute("_authentications");
    if(_auths != null) {
        List<String> auths = (List<String>) _auths;
        auths.remove(authentication.getName());
        if(auths.size() == 0) {
            auths = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
        context.setAttribute("_authentications", auths);
    }
    super.onLogoutSuccess(request, response, authentication);
}
```

does anyone give me a good solution?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

i have solved my problem, i use SessionRegistry in AuthencationProvide intead of ServletContext

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("sessionRegistry")
private SessionRegistry sessionRegistry;

List<Object> principals = sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals();

for (Object principal: principals) {
    String[] auths = principal.toString().split(StringPool.DASH);
    if(auths.length == 4 && auths[1].equals(storeId)) {
        throw new BadCredentialsException(auths[0]+StringPool.DASH+auths[1]);
    }
}
```

this code work well when session time out, user close brower. And i dont need any js source code to handle

Answer (score 0):

You can use the js below to remove user from servletContext on window close:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
     window.onbeforeunload = logout;

     function logout(){
        // Make an ajax call to remove user from ServletContext
        alert("Window close is being called");
        return false;
     }
  </script>
```

Comment: thank you for quick reply. I have a little confuse. Now I dont close browser. I enter google.com on browser, and then i close broswer. Can your code work?